# How to webscraping a specific text and convert it to a number?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, compare

I'm trying to webscrape only the number in this part, and after that compare it with another number. This number is a "sum number", it is counting how many device are avaiable on the page. How can I webscraping only this number and put it into a variable? This number is "39" in this code:

```
<div class="search-results">
                  <p class="search-results__text ff-nor fs-1-5 ng-binding">39<strong>&nbsp;tartozék</strong> felelt meg a szűrési feltételeknek a 217-ből</p>
                </div>
```

I tried this one:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
datatable=[]

link='https://....'
browser.get(link)       
time.sleep(10)
html = browser.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('div', { "class" : "search-results__text ff-nor fs-1-5 ng-binding" })
```

Comment: what library are you using to scrape? what code have you tried?

Comment: i edited my question what i tried. im using beautifulsoup

Comment: what output are you currently getting?

Comment: Is get_text() not useful? Check the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `find` and `contents`

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<div class="search-results">
                  <p class="search-results__text ff-nor fs-1-5 ng-binding">39<strong>&nbsp;tartozék</strong> felelt meg a szűrési feltételeknek a 217-ből</p>
                </div>"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('div', class_ = "search-results")
print( table.find("p").contents[0] )
```

**Output:**

```
39
```

Comment: Use the `int()` function. Ex: `int(table.find("p").contents[0])` But make sure you have a number in the html or else it will result in a error

Comment: i am sure this is not a number, its a text. In this way, how can i change it number because i want to compare it whit a number.